# Split data frame into list while keeping column values as sub list names

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I have following `data frame` and I want to keep first column values as sub list names and second column values as its elements.

**Input**-

```
var <- c("a","b","c","d")
val <- c("0-1-2-NA","0-1","0-2-4","0-NA")
dt <- data.frame(var,val, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> dt
  var      val
1   a   0-1-2-NA
2   b      0-1
3   c    0-2-4
4   d     0-NA
```

**Desired Output-**

```
$a
[1]  0  1  2 NA

$b
[1] 0 1

$c
[1] 0 2 4

$d
[1]  0 NA
```

**Note**- I also want to `split` values by `-` before creating list.

Comment: `setNames(strsplit(dt$val, "-", TRUE), dt$var)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base R solution with `strsplit`.

```
dat <- strsplit(dt$val, split = "-")
names(dat) <- dt$var
dat
# $a
# [1] "0"  "1"  "2"  "NA"
# 
# $b
# [1] "0" "1"
# 
# $c
# [1] "0" "2" "4"
# 
# $d
# [1] "0"  "NA"
```

To automatically convert strings, add `type.convert` (or `as.integer` or `as.numeric`):

```
res <- with(dt, lapply(strsplit(setNames(val, var), "-"), type.convert))
str(res)

# List of 4
#  $ a: int [1:4] 0 1 2 NA
#  $ b: int [1:2] 0 1
#  $ c: int [1:3] 0 2 4
#  $ d: int [1:2] 0 NA
```